# Angular Material2 Toolbar change color responsively

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

Is it possible to change `md-toolbar` color responsively?

I did something like this with Flex-Layout package Responsive API:

`md-toolbar color.xs="primary"`

and it didn't work.

My guess I can change it by observing [ObservableMedia](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ObservableMedia) and then setting toolbar's color in code but I'd like to know if there is an easier way.

Thanks

**Update**

I've opened an issue, as a feature request, basically doing what I've stated above. They've said [no plans](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5679#issuecomment-314537094).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, but you need to go through some css :

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import 'src/assets/css/theming.scss';

.primary { background: mat-color($primary); }
.accent { background: mat-color($accent); }
.warn { background: mat-color($warn); }
```

(Assuming your theming file is correctly placed and you used the correct variable names)

Now in your toolbar :

```
<md-toolbar ngClass.xs="primary" ngClass.md="accent"></md-toolbar>
```

Comment: Clever way of solving this problem.  